# How to distinct vendor classes and native classes in PHP autoload?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

How to distinct vector classes and native project classes in PHP autoload?
see a part of the file and namespace structure:

```
app/
app/Models/
app/Models/User.php
app/Contoller/
app/Contoller/Login.php
vendor/
vendor/company/package/Helper.php
```

Now PSR-4 says if there a class is needed to be included, autoload must include it from vendor, so how can I include my native project classes like including a model in a controller?
For Example following code:

```
$user = new App\Models\User();
```

autoload looks for "App" company (folder) in vendor folder, one approach could be use some conditions in autoload and if the namespace starts with "App" look for class in native project, is it the standard approach?

Second one, what about this, there is a package in vendor which its company name is "App" in vendor name, what is complete way?

Comment: You should ask this question on Stack Overflow, since it's about a coding implementation.  Avoid words like "perfect," "standard" and "best;" specify your criteria instead.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the 'autoloader' programs? I use the one by 'aura' : [Aura.Autoload](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Autoload). I have also used the [Symfony2 class loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/index.html). They are all standalone so can be used in any project and work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is setting PSR-4 autoloads in your `composer.json` file as the following example illustrates:

```
// Part of composer.json
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\" : "app/"
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to extra autoload, the Composer autoload will do it for you.
When the requested class is under `App` namespace, Composer looking for it in the `app` folder as it set in the `composer.json` file above.